# How does LoadBalancer forward traffic to the target service?

Tags: kubernetes

Does `LoadBalancer` use `kube-proxy` as mentioned [in this article](https://gardener.cloud/050-tutorials/content/howto/service-access/) or is it using `NodePort` as mentioned [here](https://rancher.com/blog/2018/2018-06-08-load-balancing-user-apps-with-rancher/)?

If it's in fact using `NodePort`, then why are multiple sources such as [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) claiming that using `NodePort` in production is not a good idea?

`Ingress` also operates using `NodePort + nginx`. What's so special about `LoadBalancer` then?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the cloud provider implementation:

> Traffic from the external load balancer will be directed at the
>   backend Pods, though exactly how that works depends on the cloud
>   provider.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#loadbalancer

In case of Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), [this is how it works](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#ext-lb-details):

> When using the external load balancer, arriving traffic is initially
>   routed to a node using a forwarding rule associated with the GCP
>   network. After the traffic reaches the node, the node uses its
>   iptables NAT table to choose a Pod. kube-proxy manages the iptables
>   rules on the node.